# Изображение в Блоке div

Tags: css, изображения, html

Привет всем , вопрос таков , не подскажете как уменьшить размер `div` так , чтобы и изображение которое находится в нем , тоже уменьшилось а не обрезалось.
Всем спасибо.

Comment: Задайте ширину изображения равную 100%

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #00f;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем , уже решил , вот ответ кому надо будет.

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;">
<img src="logo1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
</div>
```